# Android arraylist into db

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, insert

I'm trying to insert data from my arraylist in the db. I created this method but I get an error:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)`

```
private void memorizzaArrayInDb() {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    for(int i = 0; i < Array.size(); i++) {
        //insert in database
        cv.put(MiaTable.CAMPO1, Array.get(0).toString());  
        cv.put(MiaTable.CAMPO2, Array.get(1).toString());  
        cv.put(MiaTable.CAMPO3, Array.get(2).toString());  
        db.insert(MiaTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);                                                             
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to pretend taking care of index in loop condition and not doing it inside ?

Comment: Your array has only 1 element.  So `Array.get(1)`, which tries to get the second element, will fail.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayLists, like Java arrays, have indexes that start at 0, not 1 like other languages, see http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Arrays.

Therefore, Array.get(1) will cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException because the only element in the array's index is 0. I suggest making sure the size of your ArrayList is large enough and in context with your method.

Answer (score 0):

if you leave only

```
  cv.put(MiaTable.CAMPO1, Array.get(0).toString());
```

it will work. because your array has only one element.

and i'd recommend to modify the code into like this.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < Array.size(); i++) {
    //insert in database
    cv.put(MiaTable.CAMPO1, Array.get(i).toString());  

    db.insert(MiaTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);                                                             
}
```

or some method needs to seperate element of array and  element of element of array :)